# Parsing ambiguous datetime with Noda Time

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

I use [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org), and have the following code:

```
var pattern = ZonedDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z", 
    DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);

var parsed = pattern.Parse("2017-11-05 01:00:00 America/Los_Angeles");
Console.WriteLine(parsed.Value);
```

This results in an `UnparsableValueException` with the message:

> The local date/time is ambiguous in the target time zone

The problem, as I understand it, is that this specific time can occur twice because of daylight saving. At 02:00, the clock is turned back one hour to 01:00. NodaTime doesn't know which "version" of 01:00 that the string refers to, and because of that the exception is thrown.

To me, it doesn't really matter which version of the time that the parse results in, I just want to avoid the exception, and get a date that is as close to reality as possible. One hour less or more is OK. What would be the best way to do that?

The only way I can think of is splitting the string and parsing the parts individually, and then add one hour, but that feels completely wrong. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ZonedDateTimePattern` class has a [`Resolver`](https://nodatime.org/2.0.x/api/NodaTime.Text.ZonedDateTimePattern.html#NodaTime_Text_ZonedDateTimePattern_Resolver) property. The resolver's role is to perform the mapping to zoned date/times and handle skipped and ambiguous times - times which cannot be mapped as they will occur *never* (skipped)  or *more than once* (ambiguous) due to DST.

The [ZonedDateTimePattern  source code](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/2.2.x/src/NodaTime/Text/ZonedDateTimePattern.cs) shows that the default resolver is [`Resolvers.StrictResolver`](https://nodatime.org/2.0.x/api/NodaTime.TimeZones.Resolvers.html#NodaTime_TimeZones_Resolvers_StrictResolver). As you have already discovered, this resolver throws an exception if the mapping is ambiguous or skipped.

A variety of [resolvers](https://nodatime.org/2.0.x/api/NodaTime.TimeZones.Resolvers.html) are available. The best match for your "just give me a valid date and time please!" requirement is likely to be the [`LenientResolver`](https://nodatime.org/2.0.x/api/NodaTime.TimeZones.Resolvers.html#NodaTime_TimeZones_Resolvers_LenientResolver) which behaves as follows:

> Ambiguity is handled by returning the earlier occurrence, and skipped
>   times are shifted forward by the duration of the gap.

We can specify this resolver by appending a call to `WithResolver()` on our `ZonedDateTimePattern` instance (the `Resolver` property does not have a public setter):

```
var pattern = ZonedDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z",
    DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb).WithResolver(Resolvers.LenientResolver);

var parsed = pattern.Parse("2017-11-05 01:00:00 America/Los_Angeles");
Console.WriteLine(parsed.Value);
```

Output:

> 2017-11-05T01:00:00 America/Los_Angeles (-07)

Comment: Wow, that was easy! Thanks for also explaining in detail :)

Answer (score 3):

Per https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/2.2.x/src/NodaTime.Web/Markdown/2.0.x/zoneddatetime-patterns.md (or wherever that is generated to)

> If the pattern does not contain an offset specifier ("o<...>") the local date and time represented by the text is interpreted according to the ZoneLocalMappingResolver associated with the pattern. A new pattern can be created from an existing one, just with a different resolver, using the WithResolver method. If the resolver throws a SkippedTimeException or AmbiguousTimeException, these are converted into UnparsableValueException results. Note that a pattern without an offset specifier will always lead to potential data loss when used with time zones which aren't a single fixed offset, due to the normal issues of time zone transitions (typically for daylight saving time).

suggesting

```
var lenientpattern = ZonedDateTimePattern
                    .CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z", DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb)
                    .WithResolver(Resolvers.LenientResolver); //or any of the other resolvers
var parsed = lenientpattern.Parse("2017-11-05 01:00:00 America/Los_Angeles");
Console.WriteLine(parsed.Value);
```